# Understaning 聞く分?

Tags: word-usage

> 「自殺、ですか？」
>
> 「信じがたい話だがね。......『死霊の声』とやらに、退役してなお付きまとわれたのだそうだ」
>
> 「......」
>
> それはやはり、まるきり怪談の類に聞こえるのだけれど。
>
> 沈黙するレーナを何と思ったか、カールシュタは気遣わしげに首を傾げる。
>
> 「君も嫌ならそう言って構わんよ、レーナ。今の部隊に残りたければそれでいいし、スピアヘッド戦隊は先刻も言ったが古参兵の集まりだ。話を**聞く分**では出撃時に同調するのがいけないらしいから、最低限の監視だけ行って、指揮は現場に任せても何の問題も......」

Does the phrase 話を聞く分では mean "According to what I heard"? If it does, what would be the funtion of the bold 分? I know it doesn't mean "part".　
It seems to have something to do with この分では, where 分 means "situation". I'm not sure.
http://www.romajidesu.com/dictionary/meaning-of-%E3%81%93%E3%81%AE%E5%88%86%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF.html

Answer (score 3):

「分」used in this context, such as 「聞く分には」、「見る分には」、etc., indicates something like "as far as XX is concerned...", "from what I have heard so far...", or "from what I have seen so far..."

Here is a quick question and answer from Yahoo Chiebukuro on this subject:
[Yahoo Chiebukuro Link](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14184353054)

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain the difference between “verb+分には” and “verb+分では” since you only provide examples of the former.

Comment: Oh, apologies for not including an example for the latter. “Verb+分では” is used practically about the same as “Verb+分には” - although “Verb+分では” to me has a slightly more formal or polite tone.